# Angular package.json and unmet peer dependencies

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm trying to develop an angular project and I've been using the CLI. I'm also trying to use some other components, like the [angular handsontable](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-handsontable) and [primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/). I unraveled a huge ball of confusion for myself, however, when I just wanted to see what versions of some packages, including angular itself, I have installed.

So for example, if I want to check the installed version of primeng, I saw that I could do `npm list primeng'. I get this:

```
C:\Code\path-to-my-project>npm list primeng
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.1.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.1.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.1.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@4.1.3
`-- primeng@4.0.3

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^2.3.1, required by ng2-handsontable@0.48.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@^2.3.1, required by ng2-handsontable@0.48.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.3.1, required by ng2-handsontable@0.48.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^2.3.1, required by ng2-handsontable@0.48.0
```

Okay so... does that mean angular/common,compiler,core, and forms aren't installed? That's weird since Angular is working. Let me check...

```
C:\Code\path-to-my-project>npm list @angular/common
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.1.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.1.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.1.3
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@4.1.3

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^2.3.1, required by ng2-handsontable@0.48.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@^2.3.1, required by ng2-handsontable@0.48.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.3.1, required by ng2-handsontable@0.48.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^2.3.1, required by ng2-handsontable@0.48.0
npm ERR! code 1
```

It looks like it isn't, from what I can tell. But this is the dependencies section of my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-handsontable": "^0.48.0",
    "primeng": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

and I've done "npm install" in this directory plenty of times. And Angular stuff works...

So what's going on? I would think that with all of these @angular lines in my package.json that when I npm install, it installs those packages.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved same issue after running following instructions!

```
    npm install npm -g
    npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
    npm install
    npm start
```